# gVim displays every file with an asterisk on the right (and bold)?

Tags: vim

It looks like this:

[image]

I'm not sure but I think it started to happen when I reinstalled LAMP (Ubuntu).

All the files used to look like the ones below (no bold and no asterisk).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14):

NERDTree uses the asterisk to indicate an item is executable, I believe. At least for me, it shows up on all my .bat and .exe files.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like NERDTree. Maybe there is a NERDTree setting regarding it.

Suggestions:

1. See if the permissions or settings (do they have chmod +x) are different on the files that show an asterisk versus the ones that do not. Have you noticed a pattern between which files are bold and asterisk'd?