# vim nerdtree files show up with * appended

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, nerdtree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [gVim displays every file with an asterisk on the right (and bold)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435472/gvim-displays-every-file-with-an-asterisk-on-the-right-and-bold)

I'm using vim with nerdtree plugin for my rails projects and some of the files show up with a `*` appended to the filename. They are also a different color from the other files.

```
edit.html.erb*
index.html.erb
show.html.erb*
```

What does the `*` mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The key is the executable bit. For example, if you do this:

```
$touch no_exec_file exec_file
$chmod -v u+x exec_file
$ls -lF
total 0
-rwxr--r-- 1 reoo reoo 0 2012-09-19 19:14 exec_file*
-rw-r--r-- 1 reoo reoo 0 2012-09-19 19:14 no_exec_file
```

You can see the '*' in the exec_file, now, if you open VIM, you can see the '*' symbol again in the exec_file.

So, the NERDTree plugin shows the '*' symbol for those files that can be execute by the user.

Answer (score 6):

It means that your files are executable, meaning you gave them the permission to be executable. Or they are files like .exe for example.